# Remove AD Membership From user A if user B is not in the group

Tags: powershell, active-directory, activedirectorymembership

I am very new to Powershell scripting, even newer to powershell scripting for AD.
I am trying to basically replicate memberOf from one AD user to another
I have gotten a copy script to work, but in the cases like department transfers, I would also like to remove any access the user will no longer need. I have tried the script I have included below. It runs (as in does not throw an error), but does not make any changes.

```
$Source = Get-ADUser *ShortName* -prop MemberOf
$Destination = Get-ADUser *ShortName* -prop MemberOf
$Source.MemberOf | Where{($Destination.MemberOf -contains $_) -and ($Source.MemberOf -notcontains $_)} | Remove-ADGroupMember $Destination
```

I have seen some documentation on the Compare-object command but do not understand it well enough to see a method of implementationn using that command.
Any Help or hints would be appreciated

Comment: Let me see if I understand, say you have `sourceUser` and `randomUser, you want to remove `randomUser` as member of those groups which `sourceUser` IS NOT a member of. Am I right?

Comment: Essentially yes. Although random would be a misnomer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the code and let me know if it makes sense to you, I added comments to give you hints on the logic.

Of course, this is not the only way of doing this, but im using classic coding so it's easier for you to read and understand.

```
# Get the membership of sourceUser
$sourceUser = Get-ADUser sourceUser -Properties MemberOf

# Get the membership of destUser
$destUser = Get-ADUser destUser -Properties MemberOf

# You want to compare if the the membership of destUser is different from
# the membership of sourceUser, hence we use destUser's membership to loop

foreach($group in $destUser.MemberOf)
{
    # If this group is not in the membership of sourceUser ->
    # remove thisUser from thisGroup
    
    # Option 1:
    if(-not $sourceUser.MemberOf.Contains($group)) # This is harder to read but more efficient
    {
        Remove-ADGroupMember -Identity $group -Members $destUser.distinguishedName
    }

    # Option 2:
    if($group -notin $sourceUser.MemberOf) # This is easier to read but less efficient
    {
        Remove-ADGroupMember -Identity $group -Members $destUser.distinguishedName
    }
}
```

Edit: Adding the oneliners for reference.

```
# This is how the oneliner you were attempting should look
# I honestly don't like this for people new to Powershell

# Option 1:
$destUser.MemberOf|where{-not $sourceUser.MemberOf.Contains($_)}|Remove-ADGroupMember -Members $destUser.distinguishedName

# Option 2:
$destUser.MemberOf|where{$_ -notin $sourceUser.MemberOf}|Remove-ADGroupMember -Members $destUser.distinguishedName

# Option 3:
$destUser.MemberOf|where{-not $sourceUser.MemberOf.Contains($_)}|foreach{
    Remove-ADGroupMember -Identity $_ -Members $destUser.distinguishedName
}

# Option 4:
$destUser.MemberOf|where{$_ -notin $sourceUser.MemberOf}|foreach{
    Remove-ADGroupMember -Identity $_ -Members $destUser.distinguishedName
}
```

Comment: That worked perfectly.  I see where I went wrong when I was trying to implement the for loop. What I thought was being passed through the pipe was not. I was also treating the where loop like a for loop and expecting it to iterate through the array like object. 

Thank you!

Comment: @D1g1talArts actually you were pretty close to what you were looking for, i'll add an edit to show you how the oneliners should look. And, no problem, glad to help :-)

Comment: I'd point out the `.Contains()` method is case sensitive.  It probably won't be an issue here, but I'd avoid it. Especially because there's no tangible disadvantage to using `-Contains`, `-in` and there `-not*` variations.

Comment: @Steven yeah I didn't point this out because we're dealing with `distinguishedNames` but you're right

Answer (score 1):

To amend [Santiago's fine answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67011897/4749264), I wanted to share some of my experience with similar tasks. I've done tons of group membership reconciliation work.  I've found the most concise and fastest approach is to leverage the `Compare-Object` cmdlet.  The typical scenario, which fits here, is an authoritative source, in this case, the source user to determine what changes to make to a target, in this case, the destination user.

Most of my work has been from the group side, meaning using `add/Remove-ADGroupMember` however, this case lends itself to work on the user more directly.  It's a good use case for `Add/Remove-ADPrincipalGroupMembership`. Unfortunately, The MSDocs help link for `Get/Add/Remove-ADPrincipalGroupMembership` seems to be broken at the moment.  SS64 seems to have the help information [here](https://ss64.com/ps/add-adprincipalgroupmembership.html).

So this isn't tested but such an approach might look like this:

```
# Get the membership of sourceUser
$sourceUser = Get-ADUser sourceUser -Properties memberOf

# Get the membership of destUser
$destUser = Get-ADUser destUser -Properties memberOf

$Compare = Compare-Object $sourceUser.memberOf $destUser.memberOf

$Adds    = ($Compare | Where-Object{$_.SideIndicator -eq '<=' }).InputObject
$Removes = ($Compare | Where-Object{$_.SideIndicator -eq '=>' }).InputObject

If( $adds ) { Add-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity -MemberOf $Adds }
If( $Removes ) { Remove-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity -MemberOf $Removes -Confirm:$false }
```

The `-memberOf` parameter takes an array so you can affect the change with a single execution of the cmdlet. All done without loops.

You could potentially use the `.Where()` to analyze the objects being returned by `Compare-Object` workout the comparison:

```
$Adds    = $Compare.Where( {$_.SideIndicator -eq '<=' }).InputObject
$Removes = $Compare.Where( {$_.SideIndicator -eq '=>' }).InputObject
```

Note: Obviously if you don't need removes you don't have to implement. It's included in the examples for completeness.

UPDATE: MS Docs links are actually broken through Google. Search directly on MS and got a working link [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/add-adprincipalgroupmembership?view=windowsserver2019-ps)

Comment: Most MS Docs links (at least for PS cmdlets) are broken, I noticed this yesterday. Not sure what they're doing :/

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon I think the links are broken in the Google machine, but I got a working link by searching on the MS site directly.  Added to answer...